# Shiro or Spring Security with Ninja framework or Spark

Tags: spring-security, apache-spark, shiro

can I use Spring Security or Shiro Security with Ninja Framework or Spark Framework? I can't find any example to integrate this security frames with web frames. there is not any information in the ninja web site about user auth and web app security.

Comment: Why use Spark or Ninja. What are you goals? Perhaps there is another container that suits your need better?

Answer (score 1):

Spark has the notion of filters. http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#filters therefore you can add the Shiro or Spring Security filter. That said, it isn't as simple as dropping in a filter for either of these security frameworks. But in theory...

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite old, but I am unable to find any example of integrating Apache Shiro with Ninja Framework, so here are my findings about this.

Ninja Framework requires an instance of AbstractModule, it shows me an error when you try something like the configuration that is recommended [here](https://shiro.apache.org/guice.html):

```
package conf;

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.Provides;
import org.apache.shiro.config.Ini;
import org.apache.shiro.realm.text.IniRealm;
import org.apache.shiro.guice.ShiroModule;

class Module extends ShiroModule {
    protected void configureShiro() {
        try {
            bindRealm().toConstructor(IniRealm.class.getConstructor(Ini.class));
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            addError(e);
        }
    }

    @Provides
    Ini loadShiroIni() {
        return Ini.fromResourcePath("classpath:shiro.ini");
    }
}
```

However checking the source code of ShiroModule class I noticed that it extends [PrivateModule](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#how-do-i-build-two-similar-but-slightly-different-trees-of-objects) so this should work, at least I get no compilation errors:

```
package conf;

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.Provides;
import org.apache.shiro.config.Ini;
import org.apache.shiro.realm.text.IniRealm;
import org.apache.shiro.guice.ShiroModule;

public class Module extends AbstractModule
{
    @Override
    protected void configure()
    {
        install(new ShiroModule()
        {
            @Override
            protected void configureShiro()
            {
                //shiro recomended configuration
                try {
                    bindRealm().toConstructor(IniRealm.class.getConstructor(Ini.class));
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    addError(e);
                }
            }

            @Provides
            Ini loadShiroIni()
            {
                return Ini.fromResourcePath("classpath:shiro.ini");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to secure web restful api, suggest use the sureness - https://github.com/tomsun28/sureness
It is no specific framework dependency(support springboot, quarkus, javalin, ktor and more).
The essence of sureness is to intercept all rest requests for authenticating and Authorizing.
The interceptor can be a filter or a spring interceptor, it intercepts all request to check them.

What you need to know is that sureness is a project created by us, welcome to use.

Comment: Your only answers so far have been to promote what I assume is your own project, without stating that it is by you. Please be aware that this could be considered to be equivalent to spam if you continue to do this.

Comment: @Kemp Sorry, I am a newcomer in answering questions. I will correct it later.